# RRAS and Static Routes for VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, rras

I've searched and searched and cannot find an answer (that I can understand). Here's my situation:

I've got an office network using IP addresses like 192.168.1.1-255 and a home network using the same range of addresses. I need to VPN to work without conflicting addresses. Both networks have a router at 192.168.1.1 (I would like to keep both networks using this range as it will be a major PITA to change one of them to use a different range).

I have a server set up at the office accepting incoming VPN connections (Server2008). It has 2 network cards. I have NIC1 set up with an ip address of 192.168.1.102 and NIC2 has an address of 10.10.10.11. The VPN is set to give out ip addresses from 10.10.10.1-10.

When I connect via VPN, I can ping the server (192.168.1.102) at 10.10.10.1 (I would think it would be 10.10.10.11, but it's not). I cannot reach any device in the 192.168 range.

What I thought I need to do is set up a static route somehow that would let me access, say a printer at 192.168.1.99 by assigning somehow lets say 10.10.10.99 to 'point' to 192.168.1.99, so that VPN clients can access it.

Am I thinking about this all wrong or can this be achieved? I've tried setting static routes in RRAS, but obviously my networking knowledge is lacking as I have not been able to get this going.

Thanks for your help.